# Laptop suspends on Lid close ( Kali Linux Rolling )

Tags: kali-linux, power-management, laptop

While the terminal is updating for a few hours, if I close the lid, The terminal stops its process. This could be very frustrating in the future when I have to carry the laptop while some terminal process/ WPA crack is going on.

I don't think the laptop is broken because it was bought yesterday. I have been working on ubuntu for 2 years now, and this issue has so far never occurred.

[Things I have tried ]

Either of the following ways are not working:

[image: Tweak Tool: Don't suspend when lid is closed]

[image: Terminal : HandleLidSwitch= ignore]

Comment: Try using a more user-friendly distribution such as Ubuntu. Kali is for experts.

Comment: That doesn't help at all.

Comment: @Gilles Despite the question getting murdered by downvotes this follows my rule: It's asking about a problem Kali Linux shouldn't be doing in its `normal` use. Even if people here don't like Kali Linux its odd to downvote a question that was well written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` and change the `HandleLidSwitch=` option to ignore, then reboot the system.

You may need to uncomment the option as well.

(just typing the option in the terminal like you did in the second screenshot won't change anything)

Comment: Yeah I know, I did what you said. But When I restart logind.conf through command line, Screen goes blank and nothing happens.This seems to be a common problem which many people are facing apparently and theres no solution. And yes, Rebooting won't help. The laptop just sleeps on lid off. Help!?

Comment: Hey, Thanks. You solved the problem. The thing was that I forgot to uncomment the thing in Longind.conf! :D ( I have crippling depression )